# Building a matrix by merging the same row vector multiple times

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows, repeat, tiling

Is there a matlab function which allows me to do the following operation?

`x = [1 2 2 3];`

and then based on `x` I want to build the matrix `m = [1 2 2 3; 1 2 2 3; 1 2 2 3; 1 2 2 3]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for the [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) function:

```
x = [1 2 2 3];
m = repmat(x,4,1);
```

You can also use indexing to repeat the rows:

```
m = x(ones(4,1),:);
```

or even outer-product:

```
m = ones(4,1)*x;
```

and also using BSXFUN:

```
m = bsxfun(@times, x, ones(4,1))
```

Comment: and if I want to build `m = [1 2 2 3; 2 4 4 6; 3 6 6 9]` ?

Comment: use the BSXFUN solution: `m = bsxfun(@times, x, (1:3)')`

Comment: If I remember correctly,  using indexing is faster than using repmat.  But is also much less readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `vertcat`, like this:

```
x = [1 2 2 3];
m = vertcat(x,x,x,x);
```

Or even simply:

```
x = [1 2 2 3];
m = [x;x;x;x];
```

EDIT:

for multiples of x, you can do:

```
x = [1 2 2 3];
m = [x;2*x;3*x];  %  [1 2 2 3; 2 4 4 6; 3 6 6 9]
```

EDIT2:

For an arbitrary number of x's in m...

```
n = 3; % number of repetitions...
x = [1 2 2 3];
m = [];
for i=1:n
    m = [m;x];
end
```

Comment: the problem is that I want to pass an argument with the number of multiples. I want to do this inside a for loop and the number of times to concatenate the raw vectors is undetermined.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that in your question... (I've edited my answer)